# Tryton ERP MySQL installation

Tags: mysql, erp, tryton

I'm trying to install Tryton ERP with MySQL as the database. It's not quite clear what you are meant to do.

From the [config documentation](http://tryton.readthedocs.org/projects/trytond/en/latest/topics/configuration.html) you simply supply the uri to the database under the [database] section:

**[database]
uri = mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306**

However running **trytond -v -c /home/user/.config/tryton/3.8/tryton.conf** does not seem to get it working. When trying to access the 127.0.0.1:8050 where I've got Tryton running, I simply get **127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2015 16:55:10] code 404, message File not found**

One would assume, Tryton either installs the database on its own or you need to create yourself somehow but I didn't see any documentation surrounding that.

I've also trying adding a database through the Tryton GUI, it encounters the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tryton/gui/window/dbcreate.py", line 65, in server_change
    common.refresh_langlist(self.combo_language, host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tryton/common/common.py", line 253, in refresh_langlist
    lang_list = rpc.db_exec(host, port, 'list_lang')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tryton/rpc.py", line 57, in db_exec
    result = getattr(connection.common.db, method)(None, None, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1233, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tryton/jsonrpc.py", line 271, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1273, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1306, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1482, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tryton/jsonrpc.py", line 134, in close
    return json.loads(self.data, object_hook=object_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 505, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 389, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I've got the prerequisites installed that were listed [here](http://doc.tryton.org/3.8/trytond/doc/topics/install.html) and MySQL-python package installed, should there be anything else?

Comment: I do not think that SO, as a general sw development related site, will get you too far in answering how to install a particular ERP. You would better turn to the ERP system's own support forums or to the vendor itself!

Comment: A fair point but asking on multiple fronts may lead to a faster answer.

Comment: True, however, this is off-topic on SO.

Comment: You are right, this was off topic. Serverfault might have been a better place to ask, even then it's not quite the right place either. As a primary SW development person, I tend to go to SO first out of habit. I might need to work on that. :)

Comment: For sure you can always use the tryton mailing list, but still some people prefer to use SO, so that's why I'm subscribed to the tryton tag, so we can also give support on this channel :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a database on MySQL with it's own tools. Once the database is created you must initialize it using the following command:

```
trytond -c <config_file> -d <database name> --all
```

See for complete reference:

http://doc.tryton.org/3.8/trytond/doc/topics/setup_database.html#topics-setup-database.

Once finished, the server will ask for an admin password. Once entered you can conect using the tryton client with the admin user and the entered password.

In order to access tryton from web client you must install and configure the sao web interface, that can be found on:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryton-sao

Comment: How simple, I'm not sure how I've missed this part. Thanks.