# How to fix 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' when setting database section of configuration?

Tags: python, mysql, erp, tryton

I followed the [Docs](http://docs.tryton.org/projects/server/en/latest/topics/configuration.html#topics-configuration) of trytond and want to set the database of trytond the existing mysql database, but it never succeeded.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876789/tryton-erp-mysql-installation) is the another question I thought similar but not the same on stack overflow.
I got error when I execute this command

```sh
trytond -c <config_file> -d <database name> --all
```

I'm not sure whether the problem has relation with installing process, so the following list my installation step:
1. From the main page of [tryton](https://www.tryton.org/download)
2. Execute `$ pip install trytond`
That's all.

I added a session

```py
[database]
uri = mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/
```

And changed the default database from

```py
self.set('database', 'uri',
                 os.environ.get('TRYTOND_DATABASE_URI', 'sqlite://'))
```

to

```py
self.set('database', 'uri',
                 os.environ.get('TRYTOND_DATABASE_URI', 'mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/'))
```

These lines of code are used to config the database as my understanding.

This was the result when executing.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chenxiangjun/anaconda3/envs/env/bin/trytond-admin", line 13, in <module>
    from trytond.config import config
  File "/Users/chenxiangjun/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/trytond/config.py", line 14
    uri = mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I changed the error line from

```
[database]
uri = mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/
```

to

```py
[database]
uri = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/'
```

I got this error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chenxiangjun/anaconda3/envs/env/bin/trytond-admin", line 13, in <module>
    from trytond.config import config
  File "/Users/chenxiangjun/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/trytond/config.py", line 13, in <module>
    [database]
NameError: name 'database' is not defined
```

Is anyone know how to solve this problem or has the same experience?
This is the first time I setup an ERP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you included some syntax error when modifying the python source file. You should not modify this file but set the value on your configuration file.

The configuration file is not created by default so you should create one manually. This is a text file and can be placed anywhere on your computer, just ensure that the user running trytond has enought rights to read it.

Here is a sample one for your configuration:

```
[database]
uri = mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/
```

Once you've create this file you should execute the server with:

trytond -c

BTW: MYSQL backend is not supported since version 4.8, so if you are using a newer version you should consider using sqlite or Postgresql.

Comment: So I have to create an extra file and maybe name it ```configuration.py```, then add the database session to the file?

Comment: Oh! The command work! Thank you!
I see the error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trytond.backend.mysql'``` as you have mentioned, but it's ok.
I think it will goes well when I change to use sqlite or Postgresql.
Thank you very much!

Comment: The file may not have .py extension (which is used for python source files). I normally use .conf as extensions to indicate that's a configuration file.